# How to pass textvariable into a file

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am working on the TCL/TK can anyone tell me how can we pass a text variable into a file ?

I tried to pass the textvariable directly into file using the command

```
puts $fo myvariable
```

It only saves the my variable into the file .

Answer (score 1):

If you want a value to be present in a global variable when a file is `source`d, just set the variable before doing the `source`:

```
set myvariable "abc 123 xyz"
source thefile.tcl
```

If doing this from inside a procedure, you need to be a little more careful:

```
proc example {variableValue fileName} {
    global myvariable
    set myvariable $variableValue
    uplevel "#0" [list source $fileName]
}
# Call like this: example "abc 123 xyz" thefile.tcl
```

If you're instead wanting to substitute the variable within the file, you instead might use:

```
proc substituteInFile {variableValue fileName} {
    # Read
    set f [open $fileName]
    set data [read $f]
    close $f

    # Do substitution(s) in memory
    set myvariable $variableValue
    set data [subst $data]

    # Write
    set f [open $fileName "w"]
    puts -nonewline $f $data
    close $f
}
```

Comment: My Code look like below .

Comment: global myvariable   
grid [label .myLabel -text "Label Widget" -textvariable labelText]
grid [text .myText -width 20 -height 5] 
.myText insert 0.0 "Text\nWidget\n"
grid [entry .myEntry -background red -textvariable myvariable  -foreground white]
grid [message .myMessage -background red -foreground white -text value]
grid [button .myButton1  -text "Button" -command "click"]

proc click {} {
set fo [open "testo.txt" "w+"]
     toplevel .lvl2
     entry .lvl2.entry1 -textvariable myvariable 
     puts -nonewline $fo  
     pack .lvl2.entry1
     close $fo
     exit
}

Comment: In the example, the  value stored into the entry form using the test variable is to be stored into the file.

Comment: global myvariable   
grid [label .myLabel -text "Label Widget" -textvariable labelText]
grid [text .myText -width 20 -height 5] 
.myText insert 0.0 "Text\nWidget\n"
grid [entry .myEntry -background red -textvariable myvariable  -foreground white]
grid [message .myMessage -background red -foreground white -text value]
grid [button .myButton1  -text "Button" -command "click"]

proc click {} {
set fo [open "testo.txt" "w+"]
     toplevel .lvl2
     entry .lvl2.entry1 -textvariable myvariable 
     puts -nonewline $fo  myvariable
     pack .lvl2.entry1
     close $fo
     exit
}

Answer (score 0):

I can make your code work, but I don't like it.

```
global myvariable
grid [label .myLabel -text "Label Widget" -textvariable labelText]
grid [text .myText -width 20 -height 5]
.myText insert 0.0 "Text\nWidget\n"
grid [entry .myEntry -background red -textvariable myvariable -foreground white]
grid [message .myMessage -background red -foreground white -text value]
grid [button .myButton1 -text "Button" -command "click"]
proc click {} {
  variable myvariable
  set fo [open "testo.txt" "w+"]
  toplevel .lvl2
  entry .lvl2.entry1 -textvariable myvariable
  puts -nonewline $fo $myvariable
  pack .lvl2.entry1
  close $fo
  exit
}
```

Your toplevel .lvl2 is useless because your application will exit on button click.
Maybe it's time to read more about tcl basics.